# Calculating Leibniz of Pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, mathematics

I have this Python program for calculating Leibniz of 'pi'. I am not able to shorten it more. Can anyone here optimise/shorten it?

```
s,a,b=0,[],[]
for i in range(int(input())):a.append(input())
for x in a:
    for j in range(int(x)):s+=pow(-1,int(j))/((2*int(j))+1)
    b.append(s)
    s=0
for i in b:print("{0:.15f}".format(i))
```

Comment: Code golfing is off-topic for Code Review — see [help/on-topic].

Comment: Your question is also unclear. I see some resemblance to the [Leibniz formula for π](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_π), but I can't tell what your goal is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only micro optimization, I don't think it will make a difference, but here you go anyway:

```
b=[]
for i in range(int(input())):
    s=sum([pow(-1,j)/(2*j+1) for j in range(int(input()))])
    b.append("{0:.15f}".format(s))
for x in b:print(b)
```

- Instead of 3 loops, there is only one
- Removed unnecessary intermediary variables
- Removed `int(j)`, `j` is already `int`
- Removed extra brackets, for example `(2*int(j))+1` is the same as `2*j+1`
- Removed an unnecessary `s=0`

You could of course write the whole thing on a single line, but now that's starting to hurt readability...

```
for x in ["{0:.15f}".format(sum([pow(-1,j)/(2*j+1) for j in range(int(input()))])) for i in range(int(input()))]:print(x)
```